# Getting variables from a getOne function

Tags: angular

I am trying to get 2 variables (latitude and longitude) from data i have pulled from mongoDB. The data is console.logged as follows:

[image]

I am just trying to store the latidtude and longitude into their respective variables to be further manipulated.

```
this.getparamformid = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('facviewid');
    this.daformfacservice
      .getOneDAFacForm(this.getparamformid)
      .subscribe((daFormFac: DAFormFac[]) => {
        this.daformfacs = daFormFac;
        console.log(daFormFac, 'response of form');
        this.latitude =  daFormFac.latitude;
        this.longitude = daFormFac.longitude;

        console.log(this.latitude, this.longitude, "cords")
      });
```

the code above gets the data entry based on the _id and console logs the entire data entry `console.log(daFormFac)`
However when trying to single out the latitude and longitude and save the data in variables it does not work.

```
this.latitude =  daFormFac.latitude;
this.longitude = daFormFac.longitude;
```

Am i doing this wrong?

interface for data entry:

```
export interface DAFormFac{
    _id: string;
    author: string;
    organizationName: string;
    eventName: string;
    eventDate: Date;
    area: string;
    areaCode: number;
    disasterNature: string;
    threatLevel: string;
    surroundingDamage: string;
    facilityName: string;
    latitude: Number;
    longitude: Number;
    facStatus: string;
    operEqu: Number;
    inoperEqu: Number;
    facilityDamage: string;
    facImage: string;
}
```

Comment: Can you attach the JSON as a code snippet to the question? Look like the API returns a single object (`DAFormFac`  type), but not an array (`DAFormFac[]` type).

Comment: Hey i added the interface to the question, is that what youre asking for? the api would return 1 data entry because im trying to get 1 data entry by the id of that entry. I am however, upon  receiving that entry am trying to put the data in that entry associated with `latitude` and `longitude` to be stored in different variables to be used in a map.

Comment: Change to `.subscribe((daFormFac: DAFormFac)`. And make sure your `getOneDAFacForm` method in `daformfacservice` returns `Observable<DAFormFac>` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.daformfacservice
      .getOneDAFacForm(this.getparamformid)
      .subscribe((daFormFac: DAFormFac) => {
        this.daformfacs = daFormFac;
        console.log(daFormFac, 'response of form');
        this.latitude =  daFormFac['latitude'];
        this.longitude = daFormFac['longitude'];
      });
```

Try access the latitude and longitude as such